# No username password text box in Internet explorer 6.0.2

Tags: support, login, internet-explorer

I used to access StackOverflow with Google Chrome but unfortunately today I am trying to login from IE 6.0.2 but when Click on "Login" link I am redirected to "Login page" but there is no "username" or "password" textbox to enter, and IE hangs out for endless time. I just want to know if support for IE 6.0.2 is dropped by StackOverflow ? There is no such problem in Chrome.

> [image: Login Page Image]

Comment: unfortunately means tday I dont have chrome I have IE only.

Comment: From what I recall, Stack Overflow is only willing to go back two browser versions for support. The current version of IE is 10.

Comment: Do you really expect StackOverflow to support IE6 when Mircrosoft doesnt even :P

Comment: You can also try running World of Warcraft on DOS operating system. About the same thing like expecting a modern website to work in IE6 or Netscape 1.

Comment: Every time I see someone is still using IE6, I have to tell them [to countdown](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/ie6countdown)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack Exchange supports Internet Explorer 10 and above. Anything below is not supported.

No site should be supporting IE6 anymore in my opinion anyway. Change your browser (or if you can't, may God have mercy upon thy soul).

Comment: Got it, support is dropped from IE6. I was not aware if it. I think an alert message on click of login link is enough. `No site should be supporting IE6 anymore in my opinion anyway` are you confident about this statement?

Comment: @RaisAlam - yes.  it's over 11 years old.

Comment: @RaisAlam: Yes, definitely. As a (rather successful, if I may say) web-developer, I can definitely tell you that IE6 should die in flames.

Comment: @RaisAlam IE6 is a deprecated pile of frustrating security holes and unsupported "standards" that the web developing community has, for years now, tried to leave behind. It's a black mark on history and should be forgotten, completely.

Comment: @RaisAlam, Microsoft is actively trying to kill it off: http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards there's also those [trying to save it](http://www.saveie6.com/)

Comment: Fair enough @tombull89; if there wasn't some disagreement the world would be fairly dull. I would [counter with](http://www.saveie6.com/petition.php) _"Currently 2,679 people have signed the petition to save IE6."_

Comment: @tombull It says on the site it was an April Fiols joke :P

Comment: I am aware it was an April Fools joke.